# Spark: Conditional Expressions and Column Manipulation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with the following schema:

```
|- colA (Int)
|- colB (Int)
|- cnt  (Int)
```

I want to execute the following conditional expression (pseudo code):

```
if cnt > 1: 
  colC = colA + colB
else: 
  colC = colA
```

In the above example, `colC` is the new column created with the `withColumn` function.

I do not want to do a `collect` on `cnt`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `when/otherwise` syntax combined with the `withColumn` to create the column conditionally:

```
df.withColumn("colC", when($"cnt" > 1, $"colA" + $"colB").otherwise($"colA"))
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass a function?

Comment: @Neel, yes, you can create a user-defined function and then use/pass that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51573747/215945