# remove last pipe-delimited value from dataframe column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, split, pyspark

I am using spark 2.1 and have a dataframe column contain value like `AB|12|XY|4`.
I want to create a new column by removing the last element, so it should show like `AB|12|XY`.

I tried to split, rsplit did not work, so need some suggestion to get the desired output.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Spark SQL [`split` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) as follows:

```python
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import split
>>> json_data = ['{"c1":"AB|12|XY|4"}','{"c1":"11|22|33|44|remove"}']
>>> df        = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(json_data))
>>> df.show()
+------------------+                   
|                c1|                  
+------------------+                  
|        AB|12|XY|4|                  
|11|22|33|44|remove|                  
+------------------+                  

>>> df2 = df.withColumn("c2", split(df.c1, '\|\w+$')[0])  # split takes a regex pattern
>>> df2.show()
+------------------+-----------+
|                c1|         c2|
+------------------+-----------+
|        AB|12|XY|4|   AB|12|XY|
|11|22|33|44|remove|11|22|33|44|
+------------------+-----------+
```

If you need to do something more complicated that can't be implemented using the built-in functions, you can define your own user-defined function (UDF):

```python
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> def my_func(str):
...   return str.rsplit('|',1)[0]
...
>>> my_udf    = udf(my_func, StringType())
>>> json_data = ['{"c1":"AB|12|XY|4"}','{"c1":"11|22|33|44|remove"}']
>>> df        = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(json_data))

>>> df2 = df.withColumn("c2", my_udf(df.c1))
>>> df2.show()
+------------------+-----------+ 
|                c1|         c2|
+------------------+-----------+
|        AB|12|XY|4|   AB|12|XY|
|11|22|33|44|remove|11|22|33|44|
+------------------+-----------+
```

Built-in [SQL functions are preferred](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/732/ggbaker/content/spark-sql.html#udf) (also [here](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/732/ggbaker/content/spark-sql.html#python-jvm)) because your data does not get passed back and forth between the JVM process and the Python process, which is what happens when you use a UDF.